# How to auto resize text in fixed DIV according to the text's length?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html, fonts

I have a fixed width and height DIV, and I need to put text inside.
Problem is, this text can be in different lengths (letter-wise), so I dont mind to reduce its size once its overflowing.

But how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Better you make your div overflow, providing a scrollbar.

Comment: I can't - this is supposed to be a button

Comment: Cut short the text and put that in the div. You can check if the number of characters is more than a particular amount then cut the text and show. This won't look nice since different letters have different size.

Comment: But still, I cant know what length is rendered across browsers...

Comment: No, I suggested a character count check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle` if you target modern browsers.
It returns a collection of all real style properties applied to an element.

When you assign your text, you can get its size and compare it with the size of the div. And reduce or increase the font size and measure again.
In a few loops you should get the text in the DIV.

Here is a description: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you can't do it, since various platform and browsers render fonts differently.

And, there's no cross-browser, cross-platform method to calculate the font's rendered dimensions.

A Javascript "solution" is to check if the `div` is overflowing, and then bump up its size accordingly, something like

```
while (div.scrollHeight >= div.offsetHeight) {
    div.style.height = (parseInt(fontSpan.style.fontSize) + 1) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: fontSpan.style.fontSize = (parseInt(fontSpan.style.fontSize) + 1) +'px';

Comment: because its font-size :-) and not the height of the DIV. Cool solution man! I like it.