# Scale text string to given width

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to scale a text string's size with CSS or jQuery if the width of the allocated space is known? I need it to increase font size without wrapping the string.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<div style="width:600px">My text string here.</div>
```

I suppose I could measure the width by wrapping the string in span

JS:

```
var strWidth = $("#myStr").width(),
    strFontS = 20;

if (strWidth < 600) {
    // maybe increase font-size
    $("#myStr").css("font-size", strFontS + 1 + "px");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:600px"><span id="myStr">My text string here.</span></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Scale Text to Fit in Fixed Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165836/javascript-scale-text-to-fit-in-fixed-div)

Comment: It seems like a similar question bu the answer sounds a bit theoretical. I suppose if I knew how to "bump the font-size" up or down and then check again I won't be asking it here...

Comment: Yeah, I...sorry. I posted the wrong link originally =/

Comment: Do you want to spread the  text or increase the font size too.

Comment: I want to increase the font size.

Answer (score 2):

You need measure the width of text width given font and size. A jquery function for calculate  [textMetric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117698/765890). After than u can find a rate. And enlarge or recude the font size to fit the give element.

And here my simple example how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/PKkLL/7/

Comment: I'd like to increase the font size without it wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plugin I made, which you can use to resize the text

```
$.fn.resizeText = function(){
  var size = parseInt($(this).css("fontSize"));  
  var html = $(this).html();
  var textLength = html.length;
  var span = '<span>' + html + '</span>';
  $(this).html(span);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html);
  var newSize = $(this).width()/width*size;
  $(this).css("fontSize", newSize);
  return width;
};
```

Usage:

```
$("div").resizeText();
```

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/qFbug/1).