# How can I scale arbitrary text to always fit the viewport width?

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design

A site I'm busy working on has a section with some very large headings. There's something I'm not sure how to handle:

The heading may be one two short or long words, e.g: "Cyprus" to "Nouvelle Zelande", and it **must scale to be roughly the width of the viewport.** That means "Cyprus", being shorter, will have larger individual characters than longer text than "Nouvelle Zelande".

This would be relatively easy to do with JavaScript, I think, but I'd like to go for a pure HTML/CSS solution. So: **how can I scale text to fit the width of the viewport?** So far, I'm stumped and not sure how to do it, myself.

Some details:

- You only need to target the most recent version of each browser, which includes IE11.
- You may use any and all HTML5 and CSS3 that works within those browsers.
- It's okay if you make the text "Nouvelle Zelande" word-wrap, as long as the longer of the two words still roughly fits to the width available.
- You may add extra elements inside/around the headings.

---

**Note that viewport units are not a solution.** Previous questions asking about this ([Pure CSS to make font-size responsive based on dynamic amount of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14431411/254830), [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16056591/254830)) have answers of "use viewport units, like `vw`!", but that doesn't handle this scenario at all, and astute readers even [pointed](//stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/#comment44956933_16346076) this [out](//stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/#comment50542860_16346076). I've even used `vw` in the code sample below to demonstrate its non-solution-ness. It'll size based on the viewport just fine, but won't do any sizing based on the amount of text.

## Code sample

```css
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Nouvelle Zelande</h2>
<h2>Australia</h2>
<h2>Cyprus</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only unit, if being used to set font size, that is relative to the size of its container, is viewport units `vw`/`vh`, which will not solve your case alone, even if the container is the same width as the viewport, since it does not calc the letter size to *fit* into the container.

The closest non-script solution I can come up with is to use the CSS element counter trick, and wrap each letter in a `span`

The `130vw` I set here, worked best for the given font, though this might need to be adjusted based on which font family is being used.

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

/* 1 letter */
h2 span:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    font-size: 130vw;
}
/* skipped 2-5 in this demo */

/* 6 letters */
h2 span:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
h2 span:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ span {
    font-size: calc(130vw / 6);
}

/* skipped 7-14 in this demo */

/* 15 letters */
h2 span:first-child:nth-last-child(15),
h2 span:first-child:nth-last-child(15) ~ span {
    font-size: calc(130vw / 15);
}
```

```html
<h2><span>N</span><span>o</span><span>u</span><span>v</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>e</span> &nbsp;<span>Z</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>a</span><span>n</span><span>d</span><span>e</span></h2><br>
<h2><span>C</span><span>y</span><span>p</span><span>r</span><span>u</span><span>s</span></h2>
```

---

Here is the same concept using a script, and without the `span`'s

```js
(function (d,t) {
  window.addEventListener("resize", throttler, false);
  window.addEventListener("load", throttler(), false);  /*  run once on load to init  */
  
  function throttler() {
    if ( !t ) {
      t = setTimeout(function() {
        t = null;
        keepTextFit(d.querySelectorAll('h2'));
       }, 66);
    }
  }
  function keepTextFit(el) {
    var f = el[0].getAttribute("data-font");
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      var c = el[i].textContent.split('').length;      
      el[i].style.cssText = 
        'font-size: calc(' + f + ' / ' + c + ')';
    }
  }
})(document,null);
```

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 data-font="130vw">Nouvelle Zelande</h2>
<h2>Australia</h2>
<h2>Cyprus</h2>
```

*Note, since [`resize` events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376897/fit-text-perfectly-inside-a-div-height-and-width-without-affecting-the-size-of) can fire at a high rate, the throttler is used to reduced the rate so the handler doesn't execute expensive operations such as DOM modifications too often.*

---

If you want to make a *perfect fit*, check this post: [fit-text-perfectly-inside-a-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376897/fit-text-perfectly-inside-a-div-height-and-width-without-affecting-the-size-of)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a plugin there's

http://fittextjs.com/

wich can do that for you

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome. Thx for your answer but you may want to consider describing briefly how to use the plugin or an example.