# How to move text in a DIV in HTML (When Number becomes too big in Calculator)

Tags: html, textbox, calculator

I have programmed a simple JavaScript Calculator, but I can't wrap my head around how to fit the Numbers into the Div-Box. And to be honest, I do not realy know what to google for. I tried.

Any help would be much appreciated!

https://imgur.com/a/u6yBc1v (The Calculator and the Problem)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the size of the font to make it smaller if it touches the end of the div. Refer to this question: [JavaScript Scale Text to Fit in Fixed Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165836/javascript-scale-text-to-fit-in-fixed-div)