# Switching font-family while retaining width

Tags: javascript, css, typography

Is it possible to keep the exact width of a `<span>` while changing the `font-family` of the text inside ? I am thinking about balancing this width with `font-size` or `font-size-adjust` because `letter-spacing` will not render gracefully.

I chose deliberately two very different typefaces: Times and Verdana.

Rollover the demo: http://jsbin.com/ahiba4/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but only using JavaScript.

1. Store the container's width in a variable
2. Change the font in the container
3. Set the font size so the container matches the previous width again using one of the methods shown in these questions:

   - [How to auto resize text in fixed DIV according to the text's length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131844/how-to-auto-resize-text-in-fixed-div-according-to-the-texts-length)
   - [JavaScript Scale Text to Fit in Fixed Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165836/javascript-scale-text-to-fit-in-fixed-div) (this is the best one IMO)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you're only going to come close to the same width (less than or equal).  Font sizes are integers.

Comment: @Gilbert true, good point. There is likely to be a few pixels' deviation.